# post limitations for specified period time?

Tags: php, post

My apologize if I missing something here but now I am looking for php code that limit for post after a specified of period. so example that after click the send button it will be able to send again after x time long, I would appreciate if anyone who gives instructions, pointers, sample urls or some codes would be help me, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need to store the last time someone sent a `POST` somewhere. You have several options:

**In a cookie** - This is not as safe as the other options, as the client can manipulate / remove the cookie.

**In server session** ($_SESSION) - This is the easiest way, since you don't need to track a specific client by IP or something like that.

**In a database** - This is the most flexible way, you can easily see and manage your clients.

Each time when someone makes a POST, check in your storage when they last did a post, and deny it if it was to soon.

You could also do this on client side, using javascript. However, that's not as safe as the client can disable/manipulate it.

Comment: ah, thanks, but i am not using database, it for send email to friend, that possible use sender IP?

Comment: Then i would use a session. Just store `time()` in session like `$_SESSION['last_post'] = time();` when someone sends a mail. When they send next time, check if `$_SESSION['last_post'] > strtotime('-30 minutes');` if so, deny with a error message.

Comment: Yeah... i more understood, but i am still looking with searching for example code, thank again.

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to disable the submit button using javascript like so:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" onsubmit="disableForATime();">
     <!-- form elements -->
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function disableForATime(){
             document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('enabled', false);
             setTimeout(enableSubmit, 5000); //modify 5000 to be the number of milliseconds you would like to disable the button for.        
      }

      function enableSubmit(){
             document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('enabled', true);
      }

</script>
```

Comment: Please note, this technique can be bypassed, however, it will be effective for the vast majority of users.  Unless of course you're expecting your users to be programmers...then you'll need to use a server based mechanism.

Comment: it is also great, but it seems necessary to find how to anticipate disable of javascript, so the code can not be bypassed, more beautiful if it is with count down time, or with warning message that need x time to enable send button. thank You